# Cannot read data in SQLite db file using DB Browser - React Native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I am using SQLite for my react-native application. And I have some data stored in the database as well. But I cannot read the data in my db file in `android\app\src\main\assets` using DB Browser for SQLite. It shows empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally

`const db = openDatabase({ name: 'app_db', createFromLocation: '~/app_db.db' });`